# Create a countdown with vue.js and moment.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I am creating a timer using vue.js and moment.js, I use only minutes and seconds, my code should work, but I do not get the desired result:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: moment(60 * 10 * 1000)
  },
  computed: {
    time: function(){
      return this.date.format('mm:ss');
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    var aa = this.date;
    
    setInterval(function(){
      aa.subtract(1, 'seconds');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{ time }}</div>
```

Comment: What do you see in the Vue devtools?

Comment: @Sphinx your code will always be stucked in 09:59

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Phil pointed out, the issue is caused by reactivity issue. `subtract` just update some properties then return orginal object.

So we should have to use one new object to replace old one. (Probably exists one way to use `Vue.set` or `vm.$set` to update the properties of moment object, hopefully someone can point out.)

Like below demo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: moment(60 * 10 * 1000)
  },
  computed: {
    time: function(){
      return this.date.format('mm:ss');
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){   
    setInterval(() => {
      this.date = moment(this.date.subtract(1, 'seconds'))
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{ time }}</div>
```

Comment: Understood... For curiosity, how can I check if the time is equal to 00:00?

Comment: I tried `Vue.set` and it didn't make a difference. Vue just saw the exact same object

Comment: @Phil, I just printed the `Object.entries(date)`, it is complicated, I don't think uses `Vue.set` will be a good idea.

Comment: @CaioKawasaki, depending on your demand. above fiddle is just one demo...

Comment: @Sphinx achieved the desired result with: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqcusjLv/8/)

Answer (score 3):

```
here is example of count down using VUE with moment

<script>
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
message: 'Current Time:',
currentTime: null },

methods: {
updateCurrentTime: function updateCurrentTime() {
  this.currentTime = moment().format('LTS');
} },

created: function created() {var _this = this;
this.currentTime = moment().format('LTS');
setInterval(function () {return _this.updateCurrentTime();}, 1 * 1000);
} });

</script>
<section id="app" class="section">
<h3 class="title is-3 shadow" v-text="message"></h3>
<p class="time shadow" v-text="currentTime"></p>
</section>

<style> 
body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
}

body {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(LightSteelBlue, LightSalmon);
background: -o-linear-gradient(LightSteelBlue, LightSalmon);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(LightSteelBlue, LightSalmon);
background: linear-gradient(LightSteelBlue, LightSalmon); 
}

section.section {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
padding-top: 140px;
background: transparent;
}

h3.is-3, p.time {
color: white;
}

h3.is-3:not(:last-child) {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.time {
font-size: 7em;
}

.shadow {
text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.35);

</style>
```

Countdown component for VueJS with momentjs

[here is a reference link](https://gist.github.com/ElMatella/ed82bd9a868a6b87f8851189a8a36ff7)

alsi that's example without vue only using moment

```js
// get next Sunday
var nextSunday = moment().day(7).format("YYYY-MM-DDT11:00:00Z");

// make it a moment object again
var event = moment(nextSunday);

// get current time/date
var current = moment();

// get difference between event and current
var diffTime = event.diff(current);

// let moment.js make the duration out of the timestamp
var duration = moment.duration(diffTime, 'milliseconds', true);

// set interval to milliseconds
var interval = 1000;

setInterval(function(){
  duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');
  $('#clock').html(
      "<div class=\'days cell\'>"+duration.days()+"<span>days</span></div>" +
      "<div class=\'hours cell\'>"+duration.hours()+"<span>hours</span></div>" +
      "<div class=\'mins cell\'>"+duration.minutes()+"<span>mins</span></div>" +
      "<div class=\'secs cell\'>"+duration.seconds()+"<span>secs</span></div>")
}, interval);
```

```css
$section-color: #343436;
body {
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  color: #99999d;
}
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#clock {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10em auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
#clock .cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #1b1b1c;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
#clock .cell span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  color: lighten($section-color, 40%);
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

#clock {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10em auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(.8);
  

}
  .cell {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: darken($section-color, 10%);
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding-top: 2px;
    color:white;
  }
  .cell span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -30px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
   color:white;
  }
}
```

```html
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>

<div id="clock"></div>

<div style= "color:white;" id="countdown">

</div>
```

Comment: jQuery is not necessary, the application is building with vue, looking for vue solutions :/

Comment: may i know why you want to merge vue with it

Comment: I'm building a complex application using vue cli, and this countdown is one of the components of the application. Vue components have a specific file structure [check the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

Comment: i found Countdown component for VueJS with momentjs i will post the code and link in answer up

Answer (score 2):

This is a reactivity issue. Vue isn't going to watch / bind on method calls to your `moment` object.

You'll need to assign the result of the date manipulation back to your `date` property. You also need to clone the `moment` instance so it appears as a new value and not the same instance.

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.date = this.date.clone().subtract(1, 'seconds')
}, 1000)
```

Comment: it doesn't work..check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54dngwsh/2/) will always is 10:00

Comment: @CaioKawasaki I see. Not sure why yet

Comment: `subtract` returns the original `moment` instance, maybe it will behave correctly if you clone the result of the subtraction and assign that back to the data layer?

Comment: @Marty yup, that was it. Vue wasn't detecting an object change.